# I disabled my admin account and now I can't log in no guest account

Tags: administrator

So I just bought a used Sony vaio with the ubuntu operating system. I disabled my admit account thinking that when I powered up it would just go to the home screen. Now I can't log in. It recognizes my user name but not the password. How can I get passed the log in screen?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered before.  Here is the solution.  If this helps, please mark this question as answered.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword

In addition, this user went to great lengths to explain some caveats.

[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

(Sorry to paste links rather than copy/paste the solution, but these are both from official help wikis, so I find them appropriate for this instance.)

Again, if this helps, please mark this question as answered.